# Как добавить новую запись в таблицу БД с увеличением DATETIME на N лет от содержимого другой ячейки в записи

Tags: mysql, база-данных

При разработке приложения для колледжа столкнулись с проблемой - "Каждый преподаватель имеет дату последней аттестации, и ещё имеет поле следующей аттестации, которое желательно было бы просчитывать при добавлении даты последней аттестации. след. аттестация через 5 лет."

Понимаю, что это можно сделать в приложении, но хотелось бы на уровне БД.

Comment: `с датой промежутком на N лет` как это понимать?

Comment: Я правильно вас понял, у вас есть 2 поля. Первое значение устанавливается с тех данных которые вы передали (дата)... а второе значение это дата + 5 лет?

Comment: Промежуток 5 лет, между аттестаией и следуйщей.

Comment: Да, всё предельно верно.

Comment: Создайте процедуру. В ней определите переменную и добавьте к ней 5 лет =). Пару минут в ответ сейчас набросаю, только вот проверить сейчас нет возможности

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно решить процедурой:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `new_procedure` 
(
IN _name VARCHAR(100),
IN _surname VARCHAR(100),
IN _start_data DATETIME
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table_name (name,surname, start_data, end_data) VALUE (_name, _surname, _start_data, DATE_ADD(_start_data, INTERVAL 5 YEAR));
END
```

`DATE_ADD(_start_data, INTERVAL 5 YEAR)`

`DATE_ADD` - функция выполняющая сложение

`_start_data` - дата к которой нужно прибавить.

`INTERVAL 5 YEAR` - Сколько лет нужно прибавить.

Данная процедура будет вызываться так:

`CALL new_procedure("Иван","Иванов",DD-MM-YYYY)`

Comment: ОГРОМЕННОЕ СПАСБО! ВЫРУЧИЛИ!